# How to prevent blue dot update in Google Map V2 Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have following code:

```
private long fasterIntervalTime = 1 * 5 * 1000;
private long intervalTime = 1 * 20 * 1000;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public boolean getLocation() {    
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(intervalTime);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fasterIntervalTime);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Getting location : " + (location == null));
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

How to prevent the blue dot does too fast update in Google Map?

It doesn't call `onLocationChanged` when blue dot position is changed.

Comment: Have you implemented LocationListener in your class ?

Comment: Yeah, because I can get the lat long and not possible to copy the code as it involves many classes.

Comment: Okay that's fine, So try removing setNumUpdates method from your code because it will give you location update only single time. Read this android official document:- https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setNumUpdates(int)

Answer (score 0):

```
//stop location updates
if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

remove setNumUpdates because it will call only once